How to set up depth camera to do obstacle avoidance in navigation2
I follow the navigation2 docsnavigation2 docs and add a depth camera to my gazebo model, the depth camera works fine until I configure the pointcloud from depth camera to do obstacle avoidance. There is no obstacle generated from the pointcloud, see the picture below there is no inflation layer around the obstacle:


Here is the navigation parameters I configured for the local and global costmap:
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint: "[ [0.6, 0.4], [0.6, -0.4], [-0.6, -0.4], [-0.6, 0.4] ]"
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.5
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        scan_raw:
          topic: /scan_raw
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        pointcloud:
          topic: /depth_camera/points
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          min_obstacle_height: 0.01
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.60
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        unknown_threshold: 15
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:  # no frame set, uses frame from message
          topic: /depth_camera/points
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          min_obstacle_height: 0.01
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.7
      always_send_full_costmap: True

I want to use only the depth camera to do obstacle avoidance, but it seems does't work, and I don't find an answer from the internet, could someone helps me out, thank in advance.
Update 1:
Topic list:
/action
/action_result
/actuator_state
/amcl/transition_event
/amcl_pose
/auto_control
/battery_state
/behavior_server/transition_event
/behavior_tree_log
/bond
/bt_navigator/transition_event
/clicked_point
/clock
/cmd_vel
/config_updated
/control_charger
/control_state
/controller_server/transition_event
/cost_cloud
/depth_camera/camera_info
/depth_camera/depth/camera_info
/depth_camera/depth/image_raw
/depth_camera/image_raw
/depth_camera/points
/device_state
/diagnostics
/download_udp_packet
/evaluation
/global_costmap/clearing_endpoints
/global_costmap/costmap
/global_costmap/costmap_raw
/global_costmap/costmap_updates
/global_costmap/footprint
/global_costmap/global_costmap/transition_event
/global_costmap/published_footprint
/global_costmap/voxel_grid
/goal_pose
/initialpose
/joint_states
/joy
/joy/set_feedback
/local_costmap/clearing_endpoints
/local_costmap/costmap
/local_costmap/costmap_raw
/local_costmap/costmap_updates
/local_costmap/footprint
/local_costmap/local_costmap/transition_event
/local_costmap/published_footprint
/local_costmap/voxel_grid
/local_plan
/map
/map_server/transition_event
/map_updates
/marker
/micro_move
/nav_vel
/new_target
/obstacle_state
/odom
/parameter_events
/particle_cloud
/performance_metrics
/plan
/plan_smoothed
/planner_server/transition_event
/received_global_plan
/recharge_in
/recharge_out
/robot_description
/robot_error
/robot_mode_changed
/robot_state
/rosout
/safety_state
/scan_depth
/scan_raw
/smoother_server/transition_event
/speed_limit
/teb_poses
/tf
/tf_static
/transformed_global_plan
/upload_udp_packet
/velocity_smoother/transition_event
/waypoint_follower/transition_event

Topic info of /depth_camera/points
Type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2

Publisher count: 1

Node name: depth_camera_controller
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.10.67.02.3d.1b.0b.ff.83.7a.6b.10.00.00.3a.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): KEEP_LAST (1)
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Subscription count: 4

Node name: global_costmap
Node namespace: /global_costmap
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.10.3b.e9.a6.68.67.23.94.56.f2.22.00.00.62.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: BEST_EFFORT
  History (Depth): KEEP_LAST (50)
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Node name: rviz
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.10.3d.f2.ed.bc.2c.80.dd.53.b9.07.00.00.48.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): KEEP_LAST (5)
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Node name: local_costmap
Node namespace: /local_costmap
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.10.5b.3c.5f.81.76.d3.20.97.02.b5.00.00.61.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: BEST_EFFORT
  History (Depth): KEEP_LAST (50)
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite


Do you see any errors?
Are you sure that  topic: /depth_camera/points is the right topic for the point cloud?
Are the laser scan also being marked in the costmap? I'm not entirely convinced (but perhaps it is?) from the images that any of your sensor data is in the costmap.

No, there is no error out. And Yes the topic is right, because you can see the point cloud in the picture. I have added the picture on the question. The laser scan is from another laser scanner, currently I don't use it, because I want to make sure that the depth camera is working.
